# WPF Style - Use DependencyProperty as a CONST value

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, dependency-properties, visualstatemanager

I'm constructing my own Button with icons and text, passing as DependencyProperty colors, icon path and text. No problem so far. Here's the code for the one of the color property.

```
    //Text Color
    public static readonly DependencyProperty forColorProperty =
               DependencyProperty.Register(
                   "forColor",
                   typeof(System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush),
                   typeof(AppButtonPro),
                   new PropertyMetadata(Colors.DarkBlue));


    public System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush forColor
    {
        get { return (System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush)GetValue(forColorProperty);}
        set { SetValue(forColorProperty, value); }
    }
```

And the XAML code:

```
       <ap:AppButtonPro Style="{DynamicResource AppButtonFast}" 
            forColor="{Binding Source={x:Static const:Colors.White}}" 
            backColor="{Binding Source={x:Static const:Colors.LightBlue}}"
            Grid.Column="0" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Grid.RowSpan="1" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
            x:Name="btScrollUp" 
            Click="btScrollUp_Click"
            textContentString="Text"
            iconContentString="pack://application:,,,/DllData;component/Appearence/down.png"
            >
    </ap:AppButtonPro>
```

I'd like to swap colors at click to enhance contrast, so I'd like to assign the foreground color to the background and viceversa. I assume I can't simply invert the binding, so I'd like to store the color values somewhere in the style and use them as local variables to play in the states.
For example here's a textblock with foreground color with binding to forColor value as declared in XAML: I'd like to change it to the value of backColor in some visualstate and the change it back to normal when needed.

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="textContent" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        Text="{Binding textContentString, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                        Foreground="{Binding forColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting something here, but this seems like overkill and re-inventing the wheel. Have you looked at default Button Template? You can already template bind Background/Foreground etc and already have a VSM to handle your state changes etc, and the only thing that would be missing is the image path which you could pass through the `Tag` property all within just a stand-alone style template. So uh, is this just a learning exercise or something?

Comment: I understand the point, the background and foreground data could be easily attached to the ordinary button property, but I prepared the field for something more complicated in the future. The question remains: how can I swap the colors for example between text and background using just xaml?

Comment: Just a `ColorAnimation` in a `Storyboard` and you're done. If you care to elaborate on your overall goal this all sounds like something we could put in a single style template with minimal xaml and no code behind so far.

Comment: I got the coloranimation part, the thing I cannot manage to put into code is how to create a custom button passing two colors as parameters and then use them as variables to control the style and so the coloranimation.

Comment: No answer so far, so I 'patched' it the old fashioned way: a swap function in the target object through code. Not elegant at all, but works.